# How to achieve two-leveled app layout with Angular Material 7?

Tags: sass, angular-material

I'm trying to get my app to look and behave similar to the Angular Material website: https://material.angular.io/components/categories

[image: material.angular.io]

I've cloned https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io and run it locally, but I'm struggling with finding out the correct styles I need to apply to which elements (and I don't want to just copy everything from that project, I'd rather learn how to achieve what I want so I can apply it then to some other projects as well). I've inspected the elements and styles using the Chrome dev tools, but I was unable to reproduce it all in my Stackblitz example below:

I've started a project on Stackblitz by simply cloning the Sidenav example and adding my own primary toolbar:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-angular-io-behavior?file=app%2Fsidenav-overview-example.html

My main goals:

- Contents scrollbar should not cover primary toolbar on wide screens, but is allowed to do so on smaller screens
- Keep primary and secondary toolbars "connected" when resizing (width smaller than 600px)
- For wide screens:

  - <del>Fixed Sidenav (in a box)</del>
  - <del>Narrow scrollbar for sidenav contents</del>

Is it recommended to use flexbox to layout the whole app? And is it possible to place the scrollbars as intended using flexbox?

UPDATE:

final version:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-angular-io-behavior-with-bootstrap

Resources that helped me getting there:

- [Introduction to CSS](https://scrimba.com/g/gintrotocss)
- [Learn CSS Variables for free](https://scrimba.com/g/gcssvariables)
- [Learn Flexbox for free](https://scrimba.com/g/gflexbox)
- [Learn CSS Grid for free](https://scrimba.com/g/gR8PTE)
- [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I tried to reproduce the navbar similar to the website of Angular Material, [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-how-to-achieve-two-leveled-app-layout).

The contents of the page are separated from the primary toolbar and the sidenav.
The vertical scroll of the page is different from the side menu and does not impact the primary toolbar.
The content of the page is done through the  .

And all that was done with Flex-Layout.
I hope this will help you.

DEMO:
[image]

Comment: This helped a lot indeed. I've tried Flex-Layout a while ago but forgot about it, this made it a lot easier for me.

Answer (score 1):

With relation to your code on stackblitz, you can add below code in your current CSS :

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-mat-toolbar {
    position: static !important;
  }
  .example-container {
    position: static !important;
  }
}
```

You can read more about `@media` queris in CSS at [Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)